# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, oracle11g

Running the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TYPE 
IS OBJECT
(
  ID        VARCHAR(10),
  TIMEST        TIMESTAMP
)
;

CREATE TABLE MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TABLE 
(
  ecid        VARCHAR(10),
  startdate     DATE
)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_VIEW
OF MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TYPE
WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER(ID)
AS
(
  select 
    ecid AS ID, 
    CAST(startdate as TIMESTAMP) AS TIMEST
  from MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TABLE
);
```

I got:

```
Error at Command Line : 23 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got TIMESTAMP
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

What can be the problem?

Thanks!

Regards,András

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an object constructor for the view.  The table doesn't contain two columns in each row.  It contains an object that has two values.  So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_VIEW
OF MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TYPE
WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER(ID)
AS
(
  select MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TYPE(ecid, CAST(startdate as TIMESTAMP))
  from MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TABLE
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/053cd/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Alternatively, if you want to extract the two fields from the object, then don't declare the view to return an object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_VIEW
AS
(
  select t.ecid, t.startdate
  from MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TABLE t
);
```

PS.  I have no idea why Oracle is giving such a confusing error message.  It really should be more like "inconsistent datatypes: expected MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TYPE got TIMESTAMP".  Presumably, the error handling system is getting confused on the different levels of types.

Comment: Thanks, the constructor helped! Though, if I change the type of startdate to TIMESTAMP in the MT_TIMESTAMP_ERROR_TABLE, the constructor is not needed, so it is a bit strange, why it is needed when the value is casted.